# XL if-then with multiple tests

Tags: worksheet-function

I am preparing a sheet for sales forecasts where sales start with a trial/pilot then bump up to full capacity.  Contracts begin in different months of the year.  Sales go from pilot to full in about 6 months. Example: a contract may start in March selling 100 units, then go to 1,000 units in September.  So, I need to create a formula for units sold for each month of the year for all customers.  The test is to determine, for that particular customer, when the contract started AND the number of months the pilot will last which can be 3 to 6 months.  This dictates which month the pilot began and when full capacity begins.  I hope I articulated this well.  Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sure, we sell devices.  Our purchase orders start with a pilot, say 100 devices per month.  When the pilot is done - 3 to 6 months - the PO jumps to 1,000 per month for a year,  I'm trying to create a formula which identifies the starting month, the pilot period and fills in monthly revenue during pilot and remainder of the order.  This will bleed into the ensuing year.  Example if I want to solve for projected March '22 revenue for a particular customer, the March '22 cell needs to know if there is a PO, and whether it is in pilot stage.  Ideas?
 Suggestions?